# how to covert document.querySelector to user using react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

how to convert getting element by querySeletor to add div with ref document.querySelector to using react hooks

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
    import h337 from "heatmap.js";
    import "./styles.css";
    
    function App() {
    
      useEffect(() => {
        var heatmapInstance = h337.create({
          // only container is required, the rest will be defaults
          container: document.querySelector('.App')
        });
        // now generate some random data
        var points = [];
        var max = 0;
        var width = 840;
        var height = 400;
        var len = 200;
    
        while (len--) {
         var val = Math.floor(Math.random()*100);
         max = Math.max(max, val);
         var point = {
          x: Math.floor(Math.random()*width),
          y: Math.floor(Math.random()*height),
          value: val
         };
         points.push(point);
       }
       // heatmap data format
      var data = {
        max: max,
        data: points
      };
      // if you have a set of datapoints always use setData instead of addData
      // for data initialization
      heatmapInstance.setData(data);
     })
    
    
    
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
          <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
        </div>
      );
    }
    
    const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
    ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

how to convert getting element by querySeletor to add div with ref document.querySelector to using react hooks

Answer (score 1):

```
const appRef = React.useRef();

...

<div className="App" ref={appRef}>
```

And then to can get DOM element (the same as document.querySelector('.App')):

```
appRef.current
```

Your app renders faster that you trying to access it. You need to add small adjustments to `useEffect` hook:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(appRef.current) {
    ...your code here
  }
}, [appRef])
```

On that case your code runs only after DOM element will be mounted.

Comment: I tried using useRef the current property is undefined

Comment: You need to use it like: `useEffect(() => {...your code here}, [])` where `[]` is a dependency array, which should be empty on your case.

Comment: do i need to change container: document.querySelector('.App') to ref??

getting error 
Target container is not a DOM element.
    at Object.render (react-dom.development.js?61bb:24828)